# Is there a way to only keep the last two saved values of the recursion in a dictionary and delete the rest?

Tags: python-3.7

i am using memoization to save the last calculated values of fibonacci numbers in a dictionary. Since (i suppose) that we don't need all of the values that were previously calculated in our dictionary so, i want to delete them. specifically i only want to keep only the last two calculated fibonacci numbers, is there a way to do it?

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
cache = {}


def fib(n):
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    elif n <= 2:
        value = 1
    else:
        value = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    cache[n] = value
    return value
print(fib(1000))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found it.

```
cache = {}
for x in range(1, 1000001):
    if x > 4:
        cache.pop(x-3, x-4)

    if x <= 2:
        value = 1
        cache[x] = value
    else:
        value = cache[x - 1] + cache[x - 2]
        cache[x] = value
print(value)
```